# MYSQL Error Code: 1442. Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger Tr_Trip_insert AFTER insert on map_vehicle_person 
for each row
begin
declare master_trip_id varchar(30);
set master_trip_id = (select DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y%m%d%h%m%s'));
IF EXISTS (select mvp.id from master_plant mp 
inner join map_vehicle_person mvp on mp.id = mvp.master_plant_id where mvp.trip_id is null order by mvp.id desc limit 1)THEN
Update  map_vehicle_person set trip_id = master_trip_id WHERE map_vehicle_person.ID = NEW.ID;
End IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be simplified a lot to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_Trip_insert BEFORE INSERT ON map_vehicle_person 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.trip_id = COALESCE(NEW.trip_id, DATE_FORMAT(NOW() '%Y%m%d%h%m%s');
```

As the error tells you, you cannot INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE a table in a trigger that is the same table that spawned the trigger itself. This has too high a risk that it will cause an infinite loop.

But you can `SET NEW.trip_id` in a BEFORE trigger. As far as I can tell from your logic, you want to set that column on the row with the most recent id, so I guess you want to update the new row that spawned the insert trigger.

I had to make some assumptions about what you are trying to do. If I'm not correct, please describe more clearly what your intention is for this trigger.